# Azure Notifications Hub Namespace fails after reactivation

Tags: azure, push-notification

My Azure Notification Namespace got in bad state after Subscription deactivation. When Subscription got re-activated, all services are up and running as expected, but Notification Hubs have issues:

1. Notification Hub Namespace shows up Active, all Hubs inside show Running state.
2. When an Android device tries to register on with Notification Hub they get an exception:

> Java.IO.IOException: Unable to resolve host
> "[namespace-name].servicebus.windows.net": No address associated with
> hostname

Any ideas how to fix and if there MSFT folks looking - please check if there is a bug )